# How can I change image size using direct image url in Picasa Web Album?

Tags: google-photos, picasa-web-albums

I know I can get the direct image URL from Picasa Web Album in a Public Album. And I can also get a lot of image URL in Google Product, such as Google Photos, Blogger, and Play Store. And this URLs all have some parameter to Change the Size of image.

For example, I get this two links in Picasa

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-1vVMbu8s7d8/VlVQy4J3bDI/AAAAAAAA2vo/Npd_MTH-yLc/s144-Ic42/150724-pluto-hires.jpg

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-1vVMbu8s7d8/VlVQy4J3bDI/AAAAAAAA2vo/Npd_MTH-yLc/s800-Ic42/150724-pluto-hires.jpg

The only difference is the size, which is controlled by the `s144-Ic42` parameter. And If I manually changed the parameter, the size of image also changed.

And I get the direct link of the album cover from Google Play Store.

https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/qDjcC6p0mLI4ofiy8omX6Ej8Vq6uIv4iW9k27RoEPzBC8kUshG4c9rpXj7emGiZkFkXzAPuT=w300-rw

I found I can change the size through changing the `w300-rw` to `s0` to get a larger one.

The question is how can I control the size of photo by changing some parameter? and another question is I can I get the same direct link in Google Photos after Picasa shut down?

After a little bit search, I found this [site](https://sites.google.com/site/picasaresources/Home/Picasa-FAQ/picasa-webalbums/how-to-articles/how-to-get-an-image-of-a-specific-size) which answered my first question.

Answer (score 1):

That site you found does answer your immediate question.   But it doesn't address "can I get the same direct link in Google Photos after Picasa shut down?" - I think that the answer to that is still No.

Comment: I found if I share a photo to Google+, old design Google+ will generate a direct image url for me. And the direct link of photo is similar to the one Picasa generate for me.